# L’épreuve du Delf B1-B2

Tags: examens

Au mois de mars, je devrai passer le Delf B1 (ou peut-être B2, mais mes parents me conseillent le Delf B1).

Je ne m’en sors pas trop bien avec les mots difficiles et le vocabulaire spécifique. Et surtout, je n’ai jamais passé de Delf (je m’inquiète un peu donc...)

Pourriez-vous me conseiller un petit peu ? Comment avez vous réussi ? Y a-t-il des questions que les candidats doivent connaître ?

Answer (score 2):

Premièrement, il existe des sites gratuit pour s'entrainer au DELF, comme par exemple:

- [Préparation DELF - Niveau B1](https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/preparation-delf/niveau-a2.html)
- [Préparation DELF - Niveau B2](https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/preparation-delf/niveau-b2.html)

Ensuite je te conseille de regarder des films et/ou séries en français sous-titré FR (ou bien Français sous titré dans ta langue maternelle si tu es plus à l'aise).

Et pour finir je te conseille d'avoir confiance en toi tout simplement :)

Bon courage!

Comment: J'ai cliqué sur les liens: "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead"

Answer (score 1):

Je ne crois pas qu'ici c'est la bonne place de poser une telle question mais je vais essayer de vous répondre brièvement quand même (détenant le diplôme Delf B2).
Du coup, vous ne précisez pas si vous travaillez en autonomie, ou vous assistez au cours. Dans le premier cas voici un lien que j'ai bien utilisé pendant ma préparation :

https://sites.google.com/site/passetondelf/

Bien sûr il existe aussi une pléthore d'autres sources sur Internet parmi lesquelles :

https://www.lepointdufle.net/p/francais-evaluation.htm

Vous pourriez aussi vous tester avec des épreuves blanches

http://www.ciep.fr/delf-tout-public/exemples-des-sujets

https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/test-delf-en-ligne-gratuit-n-1.html

Malheureusement, il n'existe pas d'ouvrages avec de vieux sujets (du moins, d'après ma connaissance). Essayez de trouver quelqu'un.e avec qui vous pouvez pratiquer l'oral ; c'est mieux qu'il/elle soit natif.ve. Si vous ne le/la trouverez pas, vous pouvez parler à vous même à voix haute ! Ce n'est pas une blague ; plusieurs méthodes du français et de l'allemand que je possède en parlent. Cependant, si vous assistez au cours je vous conseillerai de suivre les conseils de votre enseignant.e qui connaît mieux que nous vos points forts et faibles.

Bon courage et bonne chance !

Comment: Je vais sur https://sites.google.com/site/passetondelf/home/delf-b1/lire-comprendre, je lis "Sorry, unable to open the file"